# AutoCompleteTextView НЕ с первого символа

Tags: java, android

Допустим, есть массив строк. Как мне подтягивать эти строки в AutoComplete, НО при вводе, скажем второго символа. К примеру: я ввожу "123", а AutoComplete выводит "x123, y123, z123" и тд.
Есть ли у AutoComplete специальный метод для этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AutoCompleteTextView input = findViewById(R.id.input);
input.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());

-------------------------------------------------------------------


public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
 private List<String> mResults;

public MyAdapter(){
   this.mResults = new ArrayList<>();
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResults.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mResults.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                   for (String el : (List<String>)results.values) {
                    mResults.add(el + constraint);
                   }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }




}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Адаптер работает так как нужно!